# Run the script after k8s pod starts

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I want to run shell script after pod startup(not immediately ). I have used lifecycle poststart . it works fine. But giving poststart hook error after rollout restart.
Please suggest some other option.

Comment: read more about graceful shutdown https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination

Comment: @kinjelom OP is talking about pod startup, not shutdown.

Comment: Can you provide the exact error for clarity?

Comment: @BlenderFox maybe, but "error after rollout restart"... maybe: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/#define-startup-probes

Comment: @BlenderFox when i do " kubectl rollout restart deploy <dep-name>" , its start giving PostStartHookError

Comment: @MayankKumar if you `kubectl describe` the pod, under the `Events` section, does it give further details about why it failed?